# What query should I write to access the information

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

What query do I need to access the info from VolSkill. I have given  to vol_id more than one skill and I want to output every volunteer and their skills based on volskill.

Comment: Please provide a little more info.  Do you want every volunteer with every skill?  You said "based on their skill," so do you want only volunteers with certain skill(s)

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat (volunteer.vol_fname, ' ', volunteer.vol_lname) as "Full name",
       volskill.vol_id, 
       volskill.role_id,
       skill.skill_name as skill 
from volskill 
  INNER JOIN volunteer on volskill.vol_id= volunteer.vol_id 
  INNER JOIN skill on volskill.role_id = skill.role_id;
```